# Why does Crawler4j non blocking method is not waiting for links in queue?

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, crawler4j

Given this simple code:

```
CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(1);
config.setPolitenessDelay(1000);
config.setResumableCrawling(false);
config.setIncludeBinaryContentInCrawling(false);
config.setCrawlStorageFolder(Config.get(Config.CRAWLER_SHARED_DIR) + "test/");
config.setShutdownOnEmptyQueue(false);
PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
robotstxtConfig.setEnabled(false);
RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);
controller.addSeed("http://localhost/test");

controller.startNonBlocking(WebCrawler.class, 1);


long counter = 1;
while(Thread.currentThread().isAlive()) {
    System.out.println(config.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("Adding link");
        controller.addSeed("http://localhost/test" + ++counter + "/");
    }

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output of program is:

```
18:48:02.411 [main] INFO  - Obtained 6791 TLD from packaged file tld-names.txt
18:48:02.441 [main] INFO  - Deleted contents of: /home/scraper/test/frontier ( as you have configured resumable crawling to false )
18:48:02.636 [main] INFO  - Crawler 1 started
18:48:02.636 [Crawler 1] INFO  - Crawler Crawler 1 started!
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
18:48:02.685 [Crawler 1] WARN  - Skipping URL: http://localhost/test, StatusCode: 404, text/html; charset=iso-8859-1, Not Found
18:48:03.642 [Crawler 1] WARN  - Skipping URL: http://localhost/test2/, StatusCode: 404, text/html; charset=iso-8859-1, Not Found
18:48:04.642 [Crawler 1] WARN  - Skipping URL: http://localhost/test3/, StatusCode: 404, text/html; charset=iso-8859-1, Not Found
18:48:05.643 [Crawler 1] WARN  - Skipping URL: http://localhost/test4/, StatusCode: 404, text/html; charset=iso-8859-1, Not Found
18:48:06.642 [Crawler 1] WARN  - Skipping URL: http://localhost/test5/, StatusCode: 404, text/html; charset=iso-8859-1, Not Found
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
Adding link
```

Why crawler4j doesn't visit test6, test7 and above?

As you can see, all 4 links before them are added and visited correctly.

When I set "http://localhost/" as seedUrl (before starting crawler), it's processing up to 13 links and then above problem occurs.

What I'm trying to obtain is a situation, when I can add urls to visit into running crawler from other thread (in runtime).

@EDIT:
I've looked at thread dump by suggestion from @Seth, but I can't find out why it doesn't work.

```
"Thread-1" #25 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff32854b800 nid=0x56e3 waiting on condition [0x00007ff2de403000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController.sleep(CrawlController.java:367)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController$1.run(CrawlController.java:243)
    - locked <0x00000005959baff8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Crawler 1" #24 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff328544000 nid=0x56e2 in Object.wait() [0x00007ff2de504000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000596afdd28> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.frontier.Frontier.getNextURLs(Frontier.java:151)
    - locked <0x0000000596afdd28> (a java.lang.Object)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.run(WebCrawler.java:259)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Comment: Why do you use a for-loop with a limit of 4?

Comment: @Seth I want to simulate adding 4 links to crawl from remote source. This number isn't significant here.

Comment: I noticed that, I'm currently trying to get a feel for your crawler, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Seth What I'm trying to reach is a crawler, running in separate thread, which is crawling only sites added by other thread in runtime. Crawler needs to wait for seeds, if it wasn't initialized with seeds.

Comment: Ah! Okay, I get it. May I ask why you do it this way? You could just collect links, wait until you have collected 10, invoke the crawling method with those links & wait again. Or is it a specific task?

Comment: @Seth I need to proccess a lot of links, crawl pages and save what is interesting for me, parse it and return product object, used by my services. Let's say I've got a file with 60 000 links to products and when you visit this link, you need to crawl at 2 depth to receive point of interests. There is a lot of files like this and each of them have other configuration (e.g. max depth). All process need to be parallel, so when I receive a link from product file, I need to add it to crawl. When crawler process this page, needs to notify other service about it, etc.

Comment: Have you seen this yet? A memory leak could very well be the answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807637/why-is-crawler4j-hanging-randomly?rq=1

Comment: @Seth I've added thread dump to post, but I can't find out how to fix this.

Comment: Am I right: You have some running crawler threads and you want to add new URLs at runtime?

Comment: @rzo Yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the problem. The problem was the same as [this pull request](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/pull/59)